# Android windowSoftInputMode adjustPan reduces the screen's viewport area by 2 times more than it needs to be for the keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, capacitor

I'm developing an Android app on capacitor. I encountered a problem that the windowSoftInputMode tag property equal to adjustPan, narrows the screen visibility area 2 times more than needed to show the keyboard. If I set adjustNothing, then the keyboard plugin's events that track keyboard startup and closing do not work. This seems like a very simple bug, but I've been trying to solve it for days now

If you look at the screenshot, you will see a gray area above the keyboard.

[Screenshot with problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUvuE.jpg)

In general it would also be helpful if you can tell me how to make the keyboardDidShow & keyboardDidHide invents run at adjustNothing value

I tried combining the values of the windowSoftInputMode field differently, but it didn't produce the desired result